# rqt_graph displays node that doesn't exist

Tags: ros, rqt-graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've encountered some problem with using `rqt_graph`. The problem is displayed on simple example in the image below. The **color** node doesn't exist (I checked it with `rosnode list` command), but it's displayed there anyway. I tried reinstalling the whole `rqt` but it didn't work.

[image: C:\fakepath\rqt_error.png]

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271205/rqt_graph-displays-node-that-doesn%27t-exist/) by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 826 on 2017-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q249553.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2